# powerpc-gcc compiles long long datatype variables into floating registers

Tags: gcc, powerpc

i have problem in compiling a C code for MPC5643L powerpc board. the code has `long long x` variable and gcc assembles it as a floating number. since my registers are 64 bit how to compile for it using gcc.

Comment: What makes you think your registers are 64 bit ? It's a 32 bit PowerPC microcontroller, no ?

Comment: no its registers are 64 bit but architecture is 32 bit. see its technical manual.

Comment: Maybe the compiler doesn't know that ? What command line switches are you passing to it >

Comment: gcc does not support this 64 bit register file in e500 compliant core(i.e. e200z4d) but i want some way to fool gcc into thinking he is building for 32 bit register file. the main point is i want it not to use floating point unit.

Comment: OK - you should probably edit your question and add all this info, as the original question is really not clear about the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would pass `-msoft-float` to the compile command line.  This will force it to not use any floating point registers, and instead treat the target as having *only* 32 32-bit GPRs.